# free app to obfuscate and minify javascript/php/html for mac

Tags: javascript, php, macos, obfuscation, minify

Im looking for freeware mac OS X Apps to minify and obfuscate javascript, php (and just minify html).

I've been looking around but i couldn't find any freeware Apps to do this, other then some online tools like [daftlogic](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm) and [google closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/), but i would prefer to do it offline, since it's for multiple files and it would be easier to keep things organised.

If anyone was some recommendations or suggestions i would appreciate,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently taken to using [Gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) for minifying my assets. It's run using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and allows you to perform a number of tasks including minifying and concatenating css and javascript.

Comment: thanks, i will look into it. If you can think of any other ideas, be sure to share :)

Comment: I have looked into it but i never got much into Node.js if anyone has other suggestions i would appreciate.
Thanks